# fontello not working on wordpress underscore theme

Tags: php, css, wordpress, fontello

I'm having a problem with Fontello - everythink is working on localhost, but when i've uploaded theme (created on the basis of underscore) on server it's not working (actually it works on main page - set as starting in wordpress - bot not on others).

You can check it on my testing domain [**webblaster.pl**](http://webblaster.pl/).

Main page is ok- on the left bottom there is fixed "socialmedia" bar - not styled yet - that's why it looks so ugly :)

But on `->fotografia-home -> kontakt` on the bottom you can see some not properly loaded fonts.

In the head section I'm attaching a css file using:

```
<link href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_directory'); ?>/fonts/fontello/css/fontello.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

I have no idea what's wrong - tried to change dir but that didn't work.

I will appreciate any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be the case that some of your css rules overrides each other.

In `/wp-content/themes/paulinakozan/fonts/fontello/css/fontello.css` there is a rule:

```
[class^="icon-"]::before, [class*=" icon-"]::before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: "fontello"; // <-- IMPORTANT LINE!
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1em;
    margin-left: 0.2em;
    margin-right: 0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: inherit;
    text-transform: none;
    width: 1em;
}
```

But another css is loaded by your site: `/wp-content/plugins/modula-best-grid-gallery/scripts/modula.css?ver=4.4.2` and there is another rule:

```
[class^="icon-"]::before, [class*=" icon-"]::before {
    font-family: "modula-icons" !important; // <-- ANOTHER IMPORTANT LINE!
    font-style: normal !important;
    font-variant: normal !important;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    line-height: 1;
    text-transform: none !important;
}
```

The second font-family definition `modula-icons` is defined as !important, so it wins against `fontello`!
This is the reason why your icons are not loaded correctly. The icons are simply not present in modula-icons.

If I open your site in chrome and disable the modula-icons rule in the developer toolbar, the social icons are shown correctly.

[image]

Comment: thank you very much for help:)
Sorry for such trivial problem. I should have checked it on my own